# Java 8 DateTimeParseException when parsing AM/PM time with DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, parsing, date, java-8

I'm trying to use Java 8's `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` to parse a formatted string into a `java.time.LocalTime` object. However, I'm running into some problems with parsing some input strings. When my input string has "AM" it parses correctly, but when my string has "PM" it throws an exception. Here's a simple example:

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class FormatterExample {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm a");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        parseDateAndPrint("08:06 AM");
        parseDateAndPrint("08:06 PM");
    }
    public static void parseDateAndPrint(String time) {
        LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse((time), timeFormatter);
        System.out.println(localTime.format(timeFormatter));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
08:06 AM
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '08:06 PM' could not be parsed: Conflict found: Field AmPmOfDay 0 differs from AmPmOfDay 1 derived from 08:06
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1919)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1854)
    at java.time.LocalTime.parse(LocalTime.java:441)
    at FormatterExample.parseDateAndPrint(FormatterExample.java:11)
    at FormatterExample.main(FormatterExample.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Conflict found: Field AmPmOfDay 0 differs from AmPmOfDay 1 derived from 08:06
    at java.time.format.Parsed.crossCheck(Parsed.java:582)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.crossCheck(Parsed.java:563)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.resolve(Parsed.java:247)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1954)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1850)
    ... 8 more
```

So `08:06 AM` is parsed correctly, but `08:06 PM` throws the DateTimeParseException with the message:

```
Text '08:06 PM' could not be parsed: Conflict found: Field AmPmOfDay 0 differs from AmPmOfDay 1 derived from 08:06
```

But this is where I got stuck.. I'm not really sure what that error means exactly, but it is definitely related to the AM/PM part of my input string. I also tried searching for similar errors but I wasn't able to find anything. I have a feeling I'm probably making a simple mistake here with defining my formatter pattern but I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You are using the wrong pattern, `H` is *hour-of-day (0-23)*; you need `h`.

The error is telling you that `H` is a **24 hour** hour, and `8` is therefore obviously AM. Hence when you tell the parser to use `8` on the 24 hour clock and also tell the parse that it's PM it blows up.

In short, read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Answer (score 8):

The pattern symbol H stands for 24-hour-clock. So the parser tells you in case of "PM" that "08"-hour can only be in the scope of AM that is the first half of day.

Solution: Use pattern symbol "h" instead (for 12-hour-clock).